# My ionic app that is asking too many permissions when installing

Tags: android, ionic-framework

Is there a way on how to customize or remove unimportant permissions on an ionic application. For instance I want to remove record audio and full network access. [image]

Answer (score 3):

Yes you need to uninstall some of the plugins for this. You will see there are user permissions in plugin.xml file of every plugin. Go through all plugins installed. This plugin.xml maps the user permissions in AndroidManifest.xml file. If you delete the plugin then you can remove the appropriate user permissions which you don't want to include.